# Hide Featured Image in AMP

Tags: plugins, post-thumbnails

We are using the "Official AMP plugin" by AMP Project Contributors.

Our posts tend to have an image inserted at the top. Sometimes this is creating a duplication with the Featured Image.

How do I remove or deactivate the Featured Image portion of the AMP posts?

In the /plugins/amp/templates/single.php file, there is this line:

```
<?php $this->load_parts( [ 'featured-image' ] ); ?>
```

I would just remove this and save the single.php file, but with plugin updates, the custom changes are going to be wiped out.

So, I can edit the functions.php file of our current theme, to "add_action", for example. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
add_filter( 'amp_post_template_data', 'xyz_amp_remove_featured_image' );

function xyz_amp_remove_featured_image( $data ) {
    $data['featured_image'] = false;
    return $data;
}
```

More info about the amp hooks here
https://amp-wp.org/documentation/how-the-plugin-works/classic-templates/